# Laravel Parallel testing with DB seed

Tags: laravel

Can someone share success story of setting up Laravel Parallel Testing with correct seeding of all DBs created for testing?

I've set up hook as described in docs:

```
        ParallelTesting::setUpTestDatabase(function ($database, $token) {
            // I log from this line
            Artisan::call('db:seed');
        });
```

Then when I run

```
php artisan test --parallel --recreate-databases
```

I see log messages for each of 8 DBs, also I have log from beginning of my main DatabaseSeeder and begging of first "real seeder" class, which is called from DatabaseSeeder. And nothing more: no seeders finished and no changes in each of DBs.

All 8 DBs migrate successfully.

```
I expect that DatabaseSeeder is run in all 8 testing databases and they all have records for the tests.
```